# Owin IAppBuilder.Map unexpectedly handling all requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, katana

```
string path = "/SomeSubPath";
            app.Map(new PathString(path),
                (application) =>
                {
                    app.Run((ctx) =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", path, ctx.Request.Path);

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    });
                });

            app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
            {
                var watch = new Stopwatch();

                watch.Start();
                await next();
                watch.Stop();
                Debug.WriteLine("Request handled in {0} [ms]", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            });

            app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", "/", ctx.Request.Path);
                await next();
            });
```

Consider the above pipeline configuration.

In my startup class, I'd like to map "SomeSubPath" to an exclusive middleware handler. Ie. Requests starting with "/SomeSubPath" should be handled by some exclusive middleware, while all other requests should be handled by the rest of the pipeline. I'm using the IAppBuilder.Map extension as found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn337263%28v=vs.113%29.aspx). To my surprise, the middleware is intercepting ALL requests, suppressing the rest of the application from processing those requests.

- Why is this happening?
- How can I get this right?

Comment: anyone? I'm struggling with this :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change this block like this. Inside `Map`, you are using `app` instead of `application`.

```
       app.Map(new PathString(path),
        (application) =>
        {
            application.Run((ctx) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", path, ctx.Request.Path);

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            });
        });
```